# Software to connect Apache Derby DB with Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, apache, jdbc

I would like to use a Apache Derby database as source for an Excel file so that I can use the tables and manipulate them in Excel.

I have tried to connect the Derby DB with the Derby ODBC Driver from Easysoft but I don't get a license. It always says that a license is already in use for my machine, but I can can't select a product in the Easysoft Data Access License Manager.

Does anyone know an alternative software which can do this?